# 1 digit number accepted in CSC field of CreditCard form in PayPal Payflow link

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

In PayPal Payflow link, When I entered 1 digit number in CSC field, it accepts and transaction successfully completed during test transaction.It didn't rise any error message.As per the user's guide, CSC should be 3 or 4 digit number.Is there any way to add or change the validation in PayPal Payflow link form.

I have tried it,but i couldn't find the solution

Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any way to add any type of validation check through your Payflow account settings.  The only thing you can do, would be to set it to be required/editable and check to see if it gets a X, N, or Y for the response and take action based on that.

Comment: In Test transaction, when I entered 1 digit number it accepts.But,In reality the CSC number should be 3 or 4.here there is a mismatch in validation.It accepts the 1 or 2 digit number and approved the transaction during test transaction.I think it should raise the validation message during test transaction for 1 or 2 digit CSC number.Please guide me....

Comment: I could submit a feature request for this feature, however I would not know when or if this would be implemented down the road, but this is something that can be passed on to our development team.

Comment: How can it be passed to your development team.Do I need to raise any request for this one.If so. How do I? Please Help me...

Comment: I have submitted the request to our development team for this issue.  However if there is a feature request that you would like to have submitted in the future for something else, you can always submit it at www.paypal.com/mts by opening up a ticket with PayPal's Merchant Technical Support team.

Comment: Thank you very much.May I know how long it will take to solve this issue.

Comment: As mentioned above, I would not know when or if this would be implemented.  Our development team receives all kinds of feature requests, and not all are implemented and the time frame varies as well.

Comment: How may I know the status of the request you submitted for this issue

Comment: Unfortunately there is no status that I can provide.  It is something that is passed on to our development team.  There is not ETA as to when this will be implemented or any guarantee that this will be something that is implemented.  It is passed to the developers a feature enhancement, and it is up to them to decide if it is something that gets implemented.